# TSQL: How to generate a random table of certain size in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

Let say we need to write stored procedure that returns couple character fields and a number.

```
A - nvarchar
B - nvarchar
C - float
```

**Is there a way to generate random table of predefined size in this stored procedure?**

For example if size required is 5 than legit result ideally would be:

```
random string, random string 2, random number 1
random string 3, random string 4, random number 2
random string 5, random string 6, random number 3
random string 7, random string 8, random number 4
random string 9, random string 10, random number 5
```

Where random string would ideally satisfy some pattern.

Comment: [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx) generates as many random bytes as you need (up to 8000).

Comment: Thanks, useful function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd need more details about each string and number but this should get you started:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.getRandomStuff (@rows int)
AS
WITH
E1 AS (SELECT v FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(v)),
EX AS (SELECT v=1 FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c, E1 d, E1 e)
SELECT TOP (@rows) 
  string1 = newid(), 
  string2 = newid(),
  Num1    = ABS(CHECKSUM(newid())%1000)+1
FROM EX;
```

and you would use it like this (here's 5 rows):

```
EXEC dbo.getRandomStuff 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rand() with newid()

```
declare @maxRandValue int = 1000
select convert(int, rand(convert(varbinary,newid())) * @maxRandValue)
```